Broken link on the on-topic page
The How do I become a quant? link in What topics can I ask about here? is broken. Please fix.

Thanks for reporting!

I updated the link to point to the Internet Archive. I hope that's appropriate use of the Archive, if someone can link to another source that would be nice.

how did you put it to the archive if you don't have the file?

The archive continuously crawls the internet to create an archive of how websites were. In this case we got lucky and the file was already in the archive.
